# Closing a jQuery dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-ui

I'm currently working on loading a dialog with a View.  This View handles both Insert and Edit for products being purchased.

The issue I'm coming across is when I save my product, I need to close the dialog and refresh a grid that was on the original page.  When I try to do so, I'm trying to find the dialog in my parent and trigger the close event.  So far I've been ineffective in finding the dialog in the parent.  I have been able to find the grid and force it's refresh.

My question is, is there a way to trigger the closing from within the dialog?  Btw, I'm not sure if this is part of the issue or not, but I'm using a full View for my dialog and not a Partial View.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Kindest Regards,
Chad

Edit: Here is my code.

View (parent page)

```
...
<div id="divPOProduct">
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var selectedIds = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#divPOProduct").dialog({
                height: 500,
                width: 700,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                open: function () { },
                close: function (event, target) {
                        alert("Here");
                        return false;
                }
            });

   //"Add" button
            $("#add-poproduct").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var link = '@(Url.Action("POProductAddPopup", "PurchaseOrder", new { purchaseOrderId = Model.Id }))';
                //OpenWindow(link, 600, 500, true);

                $("#divPOProduct").load(link);
                $("#divPOProduct").dialog("open");


                return false;
            });

...
```

View (dialog)

```
$("#save").click(function (e) {
        var validationTest = CheckValidation();

        if (validationTest) {
            var model = {
                ...
            };
            $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SavePurchaseOrderProduct", "PurchaseOrder")', model, function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    //$(this).closest('.ui-dialog-content').dialog('close')
                    window.parent.$("divPOProduct").dialog("close");
                    //$(window.parent).find("divPOProduct").dialog("close");
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

The three attempts you will see in the if statement for the result are what I have tried thus far.  I can find the parent now and the div, but not the dialog.  Btw, all that returns from result is true/false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the time being, my fix is that I refresh the parent page.  This is not what I wanted to do but until I can fix it otherwise, my only solution.  *feels dirty* Hate using this methodology.

Answer (score 1):

`enter code here`um try this:

```
 window.parent.$("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");
```

OR verbose alternate:

```
 window.parent.jQuery("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");
```

OR an alternate

```
 window.parent.document.jQuery("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");
```

One other option:

```
 window.opener.jQuery("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");
```

One other attempt: create a new JavaScript function on the parent window:

```
function closeMyDialog(){
    alert("closing my dialog");//to debug call
    jQuery("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");
}
```

then use: (on the child window)

```
  window.parent.closeMyDialog();
```

or

```
  window.parent.closeMyDialog
```

Comment: Been there, tried that.  Not to mention, that is already in my code up above...  I get the following error, pointing to the exact same line: Error: Object doesn't support this property or method.

Comment: for what is is worth, your code example posted is NOT the same - missing the "#"

Comment: I had tried your original before and had the same issue. Just tried all of the above and no dice.

Edit:  I take it back, last one caused no error.  Just did nothing, lol.

Comment: @IyaTaisho Added one more shot at it :)

Comment: FYI, I make the assumption you have `window.open(...)` somewhere and this is in the opened window.

Comment: Tried all of your new ideas and again no dice.

Comment: Not quite sure what I would need window.open(...) for. I have my dialog opening alright, if that's what you mean.  Would it possibly be an issue due that I'm using a full View vs. Partial View?  I was modeling mine after something I saw in the code base I already have, though they were using windows vs. dialogs.

Comment: I think I made the assumption based on your code it was a new window - perhaps just `jQuery("#divPOProduct").dialog("close");`

Comment: No such luck.  I'm thinking since I'm not within the same View it would have to still be window.parent or window.opener.

Comment: I finally found the closeMyDialog function, however, it can't properly execute because the function isn't finding the div.  For the time being I'm going to have the parent refresh.  It's not elegant as using ajax to update the grid but works for the moment.